# GoogleTest gtest_discover_test could not find test

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to add google test to my project and keep getting

```
"[build]   get_property could not find TARGET testcolor.  Perhaps it has not yet been
"
```

This is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13) 
project(RAYTRACE)             
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)           
include(FetchContent)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()#Redundent I know 

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

include_directories("<...>/googletest-src/googletest/include")

##GTEST##
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG release-1.12.1
)
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)



set(SOURCE_FILES 
    main.cpp
    src/Utils/testcolor.cc
    src/Utils/testcolor

)
add_executable(RAYTRACE ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(RAYTRACE
    PRIVATE
        testcolor
        GTest::gtest_main
        GTest::gtest
)
include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(testcolor)
```

Without the last line gtest is built properly and the gtest.h header is included in "src/Utils/testcolor.cc" and detected.

yet I cant add the test.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests accepts an executable name as its argument. You gave it some non-existent name `testcolor`. Your executable in your example is `RAYTRACE `. Also what is that `src/Utils/testcolor` file? And what is `"<...>"` in include directories, did you try to use generator expression?

Comment: <...> Is a path I didn't specify.
Thank you, I did solve the problem by restructering the Cmake configuration of my project

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following the [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp1ifh9TuFI&t=755s)

guide online which made me undersand my many many mistakes configuring CMake and GTest. Thanks!